# alternative to mapClickEvent

Tags: openlayers-2, java, map-drawing

I use gwt-openlayers lib in my GWT app. I have added a drawFeature control and now I want to show a radius of circle while I draw a feature. Now it looks like this:

```
vectorLayer.addVectorFeatureAddedListener(new VectorFeatureAddedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFeatureAdded(FeatureAddedEvent eventObject) {
            final VectorFeature feature = eventObject.getVectorFeature();
            if (feature.getGeometry().getClassName().equals("OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon") && !hasTemplate) {
                if (currentAreaFeature != null) {
                    vectorLayer.removeFeature(currentAreaFeature);
                }
                if (templateAreaFeature != null) {
                    removeTemplateArea();
                }
                currentAreaFeature = feature;
                Geometry geometry = currentAreaFeature.getGeometry().clone();
                geometry.transform(new Projection(map.getProjection()), DEFAULT_PROJECTION);
                geometry.calculateBounds();
                Bounds bounds = geometry.getBounds();
                currentCenter = bounds.getCenterLonLat();
                currentRadius = calculateDistance(currentCenter, new LonLat(bounds.getUpperRightX(), currentCenter.lat()));

                style.setLabel(currentRadius.intValue() + "m");
                feature.setStyle(style);
                feature.redrawParent();
            }
            hasTemplate = false;
        }
    });
```

In this case, a label with radius represents after the feature added. I want to represent a radius always `if(drawFeature.isActive)`. The first idea to realize this - using the MousePosition control. Thus I can take a second LonLat parameter to calculate a radius using my custom method `calulateRadius()`.  I hope that I can take the first Lonlat (= future center of circle) using mapMouseClickEvent. But if `drawFeature.isActive` it is impossible to handle this event. So, I am at a deadlock.
This is my solution that doesn't work:

```
   map.addMapClickListener(new MapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final MapClickEvent mapClickEvent) {
                        MousePositionOutput mpOut = new MousePositionOutput() {
                            @Override
                            public String format(LonLat lonLat, Map map) {
                                String out = calculateDistance(mapClickEvent.getLonLat(),lonLat)+"m";

                                return out;
                            }
                        };

                        MousePositionOptions mpOptions = new MousePositionOptions();
                        mpOptions.setFormatOutput(mpOut); // rename to setFormatOutput

                        map.addControl(new MousePosition(mpOptions));
                    }
                });
```